# Raspberry Pi generate tone with PiFM

Tags: c++, audio, raspberry-pi

While back I came across PiFM and decided to learn a bit about audio and modulation. I am trying to write an AFSK modulator, but first I wanted to generate pure tones, like 1000Hz. I am using code from the PiFM project (https://github.com/rm-hull/pifm/blob/master/pifm.cpp) which reads in a WAV file and shoots it out over RF. I want to do the same but I want to shoot out pure tones over RF.

Here is one of my attempts:

```
void playSineWave(float frequency, int duration, float samplerate)
{
SampleSink* ss;

ss =  new Outputter(samplerate);

int bufferLen = duration * samplerate;
float* buffer = new float[bufferLen];

for (int i = 0; i < bufferLen; i++) {
    float amplitude = 6000;

    buffer[i] = amplitude * sin( (2.f * float(M_PI) * i * frequency) / samplerate );
}

cout << "Buffer length: " << bufferLen << endl;

ss->consume(buffer, bufferLen);

delete [] buffer;
}
```

I would use it as such `playSineWave(1000, 5, 22050);` to play 1000Hz tone for 5 seconds. But I get either nothing or noise. Can you guys suggest how to fix it or perhaps some good reading material?

Edit: Changed code to fix issue with amplitude. Still no tone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's intentional to make `amplitude` change over time. Anyhow, `i / bufferLen * 32760` is evaluated as `(i / bufferLen) * 32760` and `i / bufferLen` is going to be 0 for all `i` smaller than `bufferLen` (look up integer division in C/C++), which is the case because of `for (int i = 0; i < bufferLen; i++)`.

Comment: Good eye, but still no luck. I changed the amplitude to a fixed value (see code above). All I get on the receiver side is crackling (noise).